# Can $S_{a}$ have a subgroup which is isomorphic to $Z_{b}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Can $S_{a}$ have a subgroup which is isomorphic to $Z_{b}$?

I'm trying to find out if this statement is true, and if so under what condition. I believe that it is true since we know that if a finite cycle group is isomorphic to $Z_{b}$ but I'm not sure how to formalize it.

Comment: Yes, and it's guaranteed when $n \ge m$ since $S_n$ has an element of order $n$ for each $n$.

Comment: It is true if and only if $n\geq p_1^{e_1}+\cdots+p_n^{e_n}$ where $m=p_1^{e_1}\cdots p_n^{e_n}$, where the $p_i$ are distinct primes and the $e_i$ are positive integers.

Comment: Every finite group (in particular the cyclic group $Z_m$) is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_n$ for some $n$. (Cayley's theorem, with some attention to finiteness)

Comment: @AndreasBlass we haven't learned cayleys theorem is there another way to prove it?

Comment: Yes, my comment was quite tangential because the two earlier comments already provided easier proofs.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: A group $G$ has a subgroup isomorphic to ${\mathbf Z}_m$ if and only if it has an element of order $m$. Now, given a single cycle $\sigma\in S_n$, what is the order of $\sigma$? If $\sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_k$ are disjoint cycles in $S_n$, what is the order of $\sigma_1\cdots\sigma_k$?